# Flutter Webview communication (Web with Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, flutter, vue.js, webview

**# What I tried**

1. I made a webpage with vue.js in VScode and Deploy Web page to localhost:8080
2. Made a Native App in Android Studio with Flutter
3. toast message from webview to Flutter Native App

**# Problem?**

when I click btn in Webview to send message to Flutter App
Error occured **Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postMessage')"**

**# Web Code (vue.js in VScode)**

1.main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import message from './message'; 

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(message);
window.sendMessage = message; 

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

2. message.js

```
const sendMessage = (message) => {

    if (userAgent.indexOf('android') !== -1) {
      return WebViewBridge.postMessage(message);;

    } else if (userAgent.indexOf('iphone') !== -1 || userAgent.indexOf('ipad') !== -1) {
      return window.webkit.messageHandlers.webViewMessageHandler.postMessage(message);

    } else { 
       return window.opener.postMessage(message);
    }
  }
export default {sendMessage}
```

3. App.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="btn" @click="toast()">communicate!</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import message from "../src/message.js"

export default {
  name: 'App',
  methods:{
    toast(){
      console.log("message to Flutter App!")
      message.sendMessage("hello")
    }
  },
};
</script>
<style>
.main{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
.btn{
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
</style>
```

**# Flutter Code (in Android Studio)**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';


void main() => runApp(

  MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigator',
    initialRoute: '/my',
    routes: {
      "/my":  (context) => MyApp(),
    },

  ),

);

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: EmptyAppBar(), 
        body: WebView(
          //userAgent: "random", //Add this to resolve issue
            initialUrl: "http://myipaddress:8080/",
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            //A named channel for receiving messaged from JavaScript code running inside a web view
            javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{
              _webToApp(context),
            }
        )
    );
  }
}

// Webview Native commuication
JavascriptChannel _webToApp(BuildContext context) {
  return JavascriptChannel(
      name: 'WebViewBridge',
      // A callback that's invoked when a message is received through the channel.
      onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
        print('javascript run');


      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AS-IS

WebViewBridge.postMessage(message);

TO-BE

// eslint-disable-next-line

window.WebViewBridge.postMessage(message);

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.